Microphone keyboard Light is Always On (Ubuntu 24.04 LTS)
I just switched from Windows to Ubuntu and I'm facing a problem with my keyboard.
I'm using an HP Elitebook 840 G6 and since the time I went to Ubuntu my sound and mic keys still work but their light is going nut.
my mute light (F5) no longer lights up and my microphone light (on F8) stays on.
I spent a whole day trying to fix it but now I'm in the same place as yesterday with no idea.
I'm asking for your help, please help me
Thanks in advance

please [edit] your question with they type of keyboard you are using and the keyboard media settings for mute in Settings -> Keyboard -> Sound and Media . You may need to change the settings to suit your specific keyboard. For example, I use an HP Prodesk with an HP keyboard which has the F5 - F11 keys marked for media but needed configuring in Settings to be effective.

I do not have Keyboard -> Sound and Media since I'm on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS, then I have no idea if I can configure my keyboard (I use an azerty internal keyboard)

sorry my bad. Settings -> Keyboard -> Keyboard Shortcuts -> Sound and Media I missed out Keyboard Shortcuts. You'll probably find most if not all are marked Disabled

the lamp conditions may be controlled in the BIOS. AZERTY or QWERTY would make no difference (assuming you have the correct on set in Keyboard -> Input Sources of course.

My keyboard shortcuts are well done, fn + F8 for my mic, that's why the mute works, but not the light, are you sure this option is in the BIOS? I already checked but I should have missed it.

you may find this article of interest. You can create an account on the HP Community to personalize your profile and ask a question there specific to your hardware.

I trued to land a message on HP, still waiting an answer.
If this can help, my card is a sof-hda-dsp and my chip: Realtek ALC215
